# MD5 - Online Highscore table for Blackberry. How to?

Tags: c#, blackberry, md5

I have a game made with Unity which is deployed in the WP store and I am trying to do the same for BB... however, after checking everything I have realized that I can´t post the score I have made, into the DB I host online...

I think it is because of the MD5 function but I am not sure which are the APIs, BB uses...

Can anyone help me out a little, here, please?

This is the MD5 function I have (written in C#)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;
using System;
#if UNITY_WP8
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using UnityEngine.Windows;
using UnityEngine.WindowsPhone;
#else
using System.Security.Cryptography;
#endif

public static class Md5Functions
{

#if UNITY_WP8

    static string md5val;

    // Use this for initialization
    static void Start () {
        md5val = Md5Sum("Hello World!");
    }

    static void OnGUI()
    {
        GUILayout.Label(md5val);
    }

    public static string Md5Sum(string strToEncrypt)
    {
        System.Text.UTF8Encoding ue = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] bytes = ue.GetBytes(strToEncrypt);

        byte[] hashBytes = Crypto.ComputeMD5Hash(bytes);
        string hashString = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.Length; i++)
        {
            hashString += System.Convert.ToString(hashBytes[i], 16).PadLeft(2, '0');
        }

        return hashString.PadLeft(32, '0');
    }
#else
    public static string Md5Sum(string strToEncrypt)
    {
        System.Text.UTF8Encoding ue = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] bytes = ue.GetBytes(strToEncrypt);

        // encrypt bytes
        System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(bytes);

        // Convert the encrypted bytes back to a string (base 16)
        string hashString = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.Length; i++)
        {
            hashString += System.Convert.ToString(hashBytes[i], 16).PadLeft(2, '0');
        }

        return hashString.PadLeft(32, '0');
    }
#endif
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: "I think it is because of the MD5 function" - to check I understand, you're protecting your highscores by a hash, say of the score and some shared secret / digital signature, and the problem is that all of the MD5 hashes generated on your BlackBerry version don't match what the server expects? And the only difference between the two branches is that one uses MD5CryptoServiceProvider.ComputeHash and the other Unity's Crypto.ComputeMD5Hash? Are you sure they're compatible implementations w.r.t. padding, etc.?

Comment: I know for sure, the Crypto.ComputeMD5Hash does work for Windows Phone and the other one works for a "stand alone web player" (and maybe Android, I haven´t checked it) but I do not know which is the right function that would be compatible with Blackberry.